# Communicating with separate ArcGIS Add-in?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in

Is it possible to access the functions or properties of an ArcGIS Add-in project (C#) from another Add-in at run time?

I have a custom ArcMap application extension installed and I would like an Add-in command from a different project to check if the extension is enabled and if so read/write a property from it.

I have seen this help doc but it only talks about communication within the same project.
[Add-in coding patterns](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Add_in_coding_patterns/0001000000zz000000/)

So far the only way I know how to do this is to add a reference for the extension's dll to the other Add-in projects. I'd like to set it up to be independent though.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1 and VS 2015 if it matters.

Comment: You don't really need to communicate in this fashion to check an extension; it is indeed possible to 'talk' between addins *that share the same IApplication*. To check if an extension is enabled use AoInitializeClass with the method IsExtensionCheckedOut (example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20977/list-all-active-extensions-with-arcobjects)

Comment: Thanks I can use the IExtensionManager to see if the extension is enabled. Is there any way to access its public properties?

Comment: You could have a look at the code snippet http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0049000000qn000000 if you're using IExtensionManager rather than AoInitialize to find your extensions.

Comment: Yes I can get the extension from IExtensionManager as an IExtension reference. If the extension has a public property or method can I call that and return the value? I want to use the extension to coordinate data between two different Add-ins.

Comment: is http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/shared/desktop/reference/ESRIExtIds.htm what you're after? It documents the GUIDs of several popular extensions.

Comment: This is a custom Add-in extension. Not an ESRI COM extension.